# How to resolve conflicts between plugin versions in Jekyll?

Tags: jekyll, jekyll-extensions, jekyll-theme

I'm using [Hyde](https://github.com/poole/hyde) theme and when I ran `jekyll serve` then I got the following error:

```
  Dependency Error: Yikes! It looks like you don't have jekyll-gist or one of its dependencies installed. In order to use Jekyll as currently configured, you'll need to install this gem. The full error message from Ruby is: 'Unable to activate sawyer-0.8.1, because addressable-2.6.0 conflicts with addressable (>= 2.3.5, < 2.6)' If you run into trouble, you can find helpful resources at https://jekyllrb.com/help/!
jekyll 3.8.5 | Error:  jekyll-gist
```

My _config.yml file:

```
# Dependencies
markdown:         redcarpet
highlighter:      pygments
plugins:
  - jekyll-paginate 
  - jekyll-gist
```

On checking the dependencies:

```
$ gem list
activesupport (5.0.7.2)
addressable (2.6.0, 2.5.2)
ansi (1.5.0)
ast (2.4.0)
autoprefixer-rails (6.7.7.2)
```

How do I remove the version causing issue and will it solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved the issue by uninstalling the addressable 2.6.0 using the following command:

```
gem uninstall addressable
```